# Using htaccess to redirect site root with loader

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The site I've taken over from someone else uses a loader on the index page to pull in the correct pages based on what URL is requested. For example, if you request http://example.com/services it knows to pull in the services.php page from the "views" folder. It is using htaccess to rewrite the URLs with the following

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/(.*)]+)$   ?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/(.*)]+)/$  ?$1 [L]
```

This all works great except for when you request the homepage by simply going to http://example.com in which case it throws a 500 error. If I attempt to access /index it pulls the appropriate index view as expected.

Error Log that my host gives me (not much I'm afraid, just 404s from the 500 page not being found)

```
[Wed Oct 29 15:51:41 2014] [error] [client 216.54.92.21] File does not exist: /home/hotwater/public_html/500.shtml
[Wed Oct 29 15:48:56 2014] [error] [client 216.54.92.21] File does not exist: /home/hotwater/public_html/500.shtml
[Wed Oct 29 15:48:47 2014] [error] [client 216.54.92.21] File does not exist: /home/hotwater/public_html/500.shtml
```

This site was working on a previous host but the homepage broke when we transferred it over to a new host and I can't seem to get it working myself. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: look at the server's error log for details about the 500.

Comment: Error log doesn't show anything for the 500, just a 404 for not having a 500 page :)

Comment: might have to crank up the mod_rewrite debug level.

Comment: It's a good call, unfortunately, the virtual host I'm using doesn't let me do that and they don't want to do it for me. Do you know of a way I can work around them to show the debug info if I can't do it from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be in your regex and and one last `RewriteRule` with any `RewriteCond`. Use this rule instead:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ ?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made the change, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Still 500s on the root and works fine for anything like /[anything]

Comment: Added, not very verbose though unfortunately.

Comment: Still 500, nothing in the logs now though since it's not looking for the 500.shtml. I appreciate your time on this. Very odd issue and I'm fully out of my depth.

Comment: That is weird since every 500 error wrote the cause also in the kids. Can you directly open domain.com/index.php in the browser? Otherwise try adding R flag in rule flags above for testing purpose to see what is redirected URL after this rule.

Comment: This eventually led me down the right path. I've got it working now. Not as the original designer intended, but its rolling. Thanks for everything.